# "inString not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

Working on an implementation of the Shunting Yard algorithm and I keep getting this error (In function 'void InputString()': 'inString was not declared in this scope') when trying to compile (what little) code I have - not entirely sure what could be causing it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

#ifndef SHUNTINGYARD_H
#define SHUNTINGYARD_H
class ShuntingYard {
    public:
        void InputString();
        void OutputString();
        int precedence(char A, char B);
        void ShuntingAlgorithm();
    private:
        std::string inString;
        std::string outString;
        std::stack<char> operatorStack;
        std::stack<char> tokenStack;
};

#endif // SHUNTINGYARD_H

void InputString() {
    std::cout << "Please enter an expression: ";
    std::cin >> inString;
}
```

I'm sure I'll feel really dumb when I find/someone explains the solution, but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: `void ShuntingYard::InputString()`

Comment: Change it to `void ShuntingYard::InputString() { ...` - the linker can't find the class member because you have a global function InputString instead of a class member function InputString.

Comment: `inString` is a member of class `ShuntingYard`. `InputString()` is not, and so it has no visibility to `ShuntingYard::inString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do -

```
void InputString() {
    std::cout << "Please enter an expression: ";
    std::cin >> inString;
}
```

It is only a bare function and it is not a member of the `class ShuntingYard`.
Hence it is not recognizing `"instring"`

So make InputString as a member of the class and then define it like below-

```
void ShuntingYard::InputString() {
    std::cout << "Please enter an expression: ";
    std::cin >> inString;
}
```

NOTE: Always write `#endif //SHUTTINGYARD_H` at the end of the file. It makes your code more standard.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the class name as well as the :: operator before the function's implementation:

```
void ShuntingYard::InputString() {
```

This tells the compiler that you are implementing a function called InputString() of the class ShuntingYard.  Otherwise it thinks you are trying to declare a separate function that is separate from ShuntingYard, and thus does not know about its private variables.